# Codeigniter Zip Encoding - Where is my zip folder?

Tags: php, zip, codeigniter-3

As described in the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/zip.html)

I am trying to add files to a zip folder. The data for that files is saved with my PHP variables $remoteFile and $data.

```
//Archive the Generated files into Zip for future download
$this->load->library('zip');

$zipFiles = array(
    'index.php' => $remoteFile,
    'assets/remote.php' => $data
);

$this->zip->add_data($zipFiles);
$this->zip->archive(base_url() . 'assets/remote_files/files.zip');
$this->zip->download(base_url() . 'assets/remote_files/files.zip');
```

When I load the page the Zip downloads automatically as intended. The file contents is there and everything is good. However, when I look on my server for the zip file, it is none existent.When I SSH into my server directly, or look via FTP and navigate to the 'assets/remote_files' directory for my website there is no zip file shown. I run 'ls -la' and no files.zip is shown.

Where is my zip file? Is it automatically deleting after it downloads?

Permissions:

```
:~/www-dev/site/assets$ ls -la | grep remote_files
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data admin 4096 Apr 25 00:30 remote_files
```

Comment: If you want to save zip file under any folder. Use directive path $this->zip->archive('assets/remote_files/files.zip');
$this->zip->download('assets/remote_files/files.zip');

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer to my problem. I did not realize that the archive methods path was suppose to be relative to the base URL. I thought it had to be absolute and needed me to define the base url in the path.